# How to show or hide activity indicator in song loading time in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

I am working in AVAudioplayer in iOS. I am displaying an activity indicator for loading time if a user clicks the play button. My problem is that when I click the play button the loading time activity indicator is  displayed. In playing time also activity indicator displayed that is my problem.i need to hidden activity indicator in song playing time

```
- (void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

  [self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

  if (playing == NO)

  {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

    // Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Buttomn

    NSError *err = nil;

    if (!audioPlayer)

    {

      [self loadSongAtIndex:selectedIndex];

      playing = YES;
    }

    if (err)

    {

      NSLog(@"Error %ld,%@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);
    }

    NSTimeInterval bufferDuration = 0.005;

    [audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:bufferDuration error:&err];

    if (err)

    {

      NSLog(@"Error %ld, %@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);
    }

    double sampleRate = 44100.0;

    [audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:sampleRate error:&err];

    if (err)

    {

      NSLog(@"Error %ld, %@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);
    }

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

    if (err)

    {

      NSLog(@"Error %ld,%@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);
    }

    sampRate = audioSession.sampleRate;

    bufferDuration = audioSession.IOBufferDuration;

    NSLog(@"SampeRate:%0.0fHZI/OBufferDuration:%f", sampleRate, bufferDuration);

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [audioPlayer play];

    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    if (!audioPlayer.playing)

    {

      [audioPlayer play];

      activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
          initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

      [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];

      self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(
          self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);

      [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

      [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];

    }

    else if (audioPlayer.playing == YES)

      [audioPlayer play];

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    playing = YES;

  }

  else if (playing == YES)

  {

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];

    [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play12.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

    [audioPlayer pause];

    playing = NO;

    timer = [NSTimer
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                target:self
                              selector:@selector(updateViewForPlayerState)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice  `[bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];` is executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add it as subview after you stop it? 
You could either set its alpha to 0.0 or remove from superview:

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
[bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

After stopping activity indicator you don't add to bg_Image.
Still you got the same issue you can use threads.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stopIndicator:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

-(void)stopIndicator
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```